# findOrFail() method not found by PhpStorm

Tags: laravel, eloquent, ide, phpstorm

PhpStorm does not found `findOrFail()` method. When I try to call it, there isn't auto-complete and the result is always fail. The user found is always on the message.

I try to use Laravel Ide helper and `query()->findorfail` but I didn't resolve.

[image]

The result:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

in phpstorm try the Laravel plugin to generate the IDE classes.

Answer (score -1):

please check your User model. It must extend Model class like this.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Lead extends Model {
```

I guess your User model is missing this "extends Model".

Answer (score -1):

As I know, PHPStorm never detects the `findOrFail` method even we already installed the Laravel plugin.

But you use it wrong because this method takes an id and returns a single model. If the method can't find any matching data, it will return an error.

You can change the method into:

```
User::findOrFail($user->id);
```